# How to use arm_neon intrinsics to calcutale product matrices whose length CANNOT be devided by 4?

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, simd, intrinsics, neon

I'm learning how to use neon intrinsics recently. I have understood how to calculate matrix product like (8*8)*(8*8) matrices, whose length of edge can be devided by 4.

Here is the solution:https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102467/0100/Matrix-multiplication-example

But how can I use neon intrinsics to calculate matrices product like (10*10)*(10*10)?

Comment: I think unfortunately there is no predication of the vector registers like with the ARM SVE intrinsics. 

One solution is to implement a remainder / peel loop for the remaining iterations that uses scalar instructions. Or you could look into the [Neon Intrinsics Reference](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/simd-isas/neon/intrinsics) for a masked load/store and throw away unused remaining vector elements.

Comment: Have you looked at how the Eigen template library does it?  You might be able to use 8-byte vectors for the last 2 elements of a row, or an 8-byte load that zero-extends to 16 bytes.